# How to add WifiConfiguration with HttpProxy set on Android 8 & 9

Tags: java, android, proxy, wifimanager, wifi

I need to add a WifiConfiguration with proxy settings to the WifiManager.
I can add the configuration successfully when I don't use the sethttpProxy (I don't add the proxy at all) but when I use the method wifiConfiguration.sethttpProxy() and then addNetwork(wifiConfiguration) the network configuration is not added.

I have tried this on a physical device with a different configuration and now I am testing this on the emulator. The emulator has a default Wi-Fi network AndroidWifi and I am trying to add a configuration for it. Before I try it I delete any “saved networks” using the system menu in order to make sure my app can create and edit this configuration.

```
WifiConfiguration configuration = new WifiConfiguration();
configuration.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
configuration.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
configuration.setHttpProxy(ProxyInfo.buildDirectProxy(proxyData.proxy_host,
                             proxyData.proxy_port, proxyData.proxy_exception));
wifiManager.addNetwork(configuration);
```

The addNetwork returns -1 and I get an error like

E/WifiConfigManager: UID 10086 does not have permission to modify proxy Settings "AndroidWifi"NONE. Must have NETWORK_SETTINGS, or be device or profile owner.
E/WifiConfigManager: Failed to add/update network AndroidWifi

Answer (score 0):

As it says in the error you get, you need to have NETWORK_SETTINGS privilege or be device/profile owner. It's some rule set since Android 8 see [here](https://developer.android.com/work/versions/android-8.0#wi-fi_proxy_configuration).

I had this same issue when trying to set proxy settings for a wifi network on my LG Q7 manually in Settings on the device. For some reason default Settings app didn't have this handled. Anyway I've bypassed it with help from [adb-join-wifi](https://github.com/steinwurf/adb-join-wifi) app which I believe will show you how to do this programmatically.

Key here is that you set your application that uses `setHttpProxy` as a Device Owner (can be temporarily) which you can do with `dpm` tool from `adb` shell as is described on the Github page of the project.